# Nodejs Formdata file upload

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting my image object from canvas and converting it into blob and then to file in java script

```
        var sendingData = new FormData();
        var ctx = mainCanvas.getContext("2d");
        console.log("canveas content =" + noofchildren.get(i));
        ctx.drawImage(noofchildren.get(i), 0, 0, mainCanvas.width, mainCanvas.height);

        var b64Data = mainCanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.7).split(",")[1];
        var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
        var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
        for (var j = 0; j < byteCharacters.length; j++) {
            byteNumbers[j] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(j);
        }
        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
        var blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: contentType });
        var file = new File([blob], "sample.JPG", { type: "image/jpeg" });

        sendingData.append(nameOfTheImageFiles[i], file);

        var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/" + email + "/imagesupload",
        contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
        processData: false,
        data: sendingData
    }).success(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $("#image-container").children().remove();
    });
```

i am using ajax to post my file to nodejs server

and req.files is an empty object in nodejs

How to resolve?

In asp.net I am getting the file on post method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the documentation of [`FormData.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append), you can see that you can only have a `File` as value when you have specified the third `filename` parameter. So try swapping the relevant line to the following

```
sendingData.append(nameOfTheImageFiles[i], file, "sample.JPG");
```